# Data is not getting fetched from MySQL Database while creating an application from Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, mysql-workbench

I recently began working on creating a REST API using **Spring Boot**. While running the code, though I don't get any error, I get a blank screen when using `localhost:8080/expenses/` and I'm not sure why.

**My Entity Class**

```
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.sql.Date;

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "tbl_expenses")
public class Expense {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name ="expense_name")
    private String name;


    private String description;


    @Column(name ="expense_amount")
    private BigDecimal amount;
    private String category;
    private Date date;

}
```

**My Expense Controller**

```
package in.pranay.expensetrackerapi.controller;


import in.pranay.expensetrackerapi.entity.Expense;
import in.pranay.expensetrackerapi.service.ExpenseService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.List;

@RestController
public class ExpenseController {

    @Autowired
    private ExpenseService expenseService;

    @GetMapping("/expenses")
    public List<Expense> getAllExpenses() {
        return expenseService.getAllExpenses();
    }

}
```

**My Repository**

```
package in.pranay.expensetrackerapi.repository;

import in.pranay.expensetrackerapi.entity.Expense;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface ExpenseRepository extends JpaRepository<Expense, Long> {
}
```

**My Application.properties**

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/expensetracker
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=pranay@1404
```

Can anyone please help me solve the issue?

Comment: what is your service class `expenseService.getAllExpenses()` doing?

Comment: When you get a blank screen and don't know why, why do you assume that no data is returned from the database? As it stands the problem could be anywhere in the application stack, most of which we don't see. 

Write some tests to isolate the problem, please. Then come back with a more focused question.